# Question about sentence structure of following sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a question about the sentence structure of following sentence.

> Company A shall:
>   (a) not engage in actions that are, or *include the Products, Marks or Company B's name in any material,* that is:
>       (i) publicly sexual, pornographic, . . .  or
>       (ii) tortious, defamatory, . . .

I can't understand the part "or include the Products, Marks or Company B's name in any material".
For the first half, I assume it means "Company A shall not engage in actions that are publicly sexual, pornographic, . . ."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's effectively *domain-specific proofreading / interpretation*. For example, I doubt 1 in 100 native speakers would recognise the otherwise-obsolete term ***tortious***.

Comment: Except it isn't...  Despite the fact that it may use an uncommon word, the question is about a difficult-to-parse sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could certainly stand to be written more clearly.  It's two sentences in one!

> Company A shall not engage in actions that are:
>
> (i) publicly....
>
> (ii) tortious...

And

> Company A shall not include the Products, Marks or Company B's name in
>   any material that is:
>
> (i) publicly...
>
> (ii) tortious...

Basically, Company A shouldn't do any of this stuff, and it shouldn't associate Company B with any of this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to observe the *numbering convention*.

Where a multi-point legal statement uses a), b), c) etc. you should theoretically be able to break the sentence at any of those points and it'd still make sense.

For example:

> You must not:
>   a) do this, or
>   b) do that.

In your example there is a point numbered "**a)**" but you never get to "b)" so effectively we can ignore that. However, there are two inline points numbered "i" and "ii". This is a different *numbering convention* (i.e. using roman numerals instead of alphabetical characters) to denote that it is *distinct*. Normally a legal document is *formatted* in such a way to show that these are distinct. Perhaps that formatting is lost in your quote.

If you break it down you could understand that *all* of these are true:

1. Company A shall not engage in actions that are publicly sexual, pornographic, tortious or defamatory
2. Company A shall not include the Products, Marks or Company B's name in any material, that is publicly sexual, pornographic, tortious or defamatory

Because points (i) and (ii) are sub-points of section (a), they do not apply to any section (b) which may have similarly numbered sub-points of its own.